# Web browser control display plain text mail

Tags: c#, .net, web-controls

I have a c# app which is supposed to display email. the email may be HTML or plain text but i am using web browser control in both cases. the problem is web browser control is ignoring all the escape characters of plain text and the mail appear as a single line.

the work around i am using is to replace escape character "\n" or "\r" to `<br>`. is there any other good way to do this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: replacing \n and \r to &lt; br &gt;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can surround the text with `<pre>` and `</pre>` (stands for "preformatted") tag. See here: [HTML pre Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)

Answer (score 3):

I think, the only way is the replacing "\r\n" for `<br/>`.
Use the StringBuilder class for it.

```
var htmlText = new StringBuilder(text);
htmlText.Replace("\r\n", "\n")
        .Replace("\r", "\n")
        .Replace("\n", "<br/>");
webBrowser.DocumentText = htmlText.ToString();
```

Comment: What if the email has intented `\r\n` text? For example, what if I send a piece of code to someone through email? In that case, this logic will render email incorrectly and code will be displayed changed.

Comment: @MangeshGhotage In that case you need parse the content and replace newlines only in parts where you want to.